# Enable intranet web application to all signed Windows users

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication, iis

I have an ASP.NET app. It needs to be available to any signed Windows user over local network. At the moment user enters the site I would like to identify him by his Windows name. Anonymous users are not allowed.

What do I have:
In `web.config:`

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
     <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
         <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization> 
</system.web>
```

In `applicationhost.config` for IIS Express:

```
  <authentication>
     <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" userName="" />
     <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
           <providers>
             <add value="NTLM" />
            </providers>
     </windowsAuthentication>
  </authentication>
```

Currently I am having an issue if getting "authorization required" form in browser instead of getting to the app. Any suggestions?

There is a guess, that problem is more about IIS version/settings then with project itself.

Comment: Are you running this in a local domain, or just a workgroup? Are they domain users or local users?

Comment: @RonBeyer Currently i am testing on single PC, so users are local. Target is to make it work for domain users.

Comment: Does that mean that the computer you are hosting the site with, and the computer you are accessing the site with are the same computer? Or is the server on another machine?

Comment: @RonBeyer  Yes, currently this is a problem on the same computer which runs IIS Express. I debug the app by running it from MS VS 2013 in Chrome/Firefox. App is placed on localhost.